# How to handle single quotes inside an ssh command with double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have a requirement where i need to use an argument having single quotes in current and remote server something like below

```
var1=$2
var2=`echo $var1|sed -r "s/'/\\\\\'/g"`
echo "echo \\\"$var2\\\" && ssh id@server \\\" echo \\\"$var2\\\" \\\" " > sql1.txt
xargs --arg-file=sql1.txt --max-procs=$1 --replace --verbose /bin/sh -c "{}"
```

After escaping quote, the argument is populating perfectly in current server but on remote server single quotes are not showing up.

```
ksh script.ksh 2 "tablename where last_load_dt = '2020-06-19'"
```

output

```
/bin/sh -c echo "tablename where last_load_dt = '2020-06-19'" && ssh id@server "echo "tablename where last_load_dt = '2020-06-19'" "
tablename where last_load_dt = '2020-06-19'
---ssh to remote server---
tablename where last_load_dt = 2020-06-19
```

How to get single quote populated correctly in remote server?

Comment: @thatotherguy It's written to `sql1.txt`.

Comment: Ignoring *how* you are doing it for the moment, *what* do you want to do? Multiple layers of quoting and escaping usually means you approaching this in the wrong way.

Comment: SSH requires an additional layer of escaping. Here's an easier repro: `echo "'hi'"; ssh localhost echo "'hi'"; ssh localhost "echo \"'hi'\""` . You should definitely take a step back and rethink the approach though, since this method is both cumbersome and error prone. If you want to run commands in parallel, you can use a simple loop with `sem` and `printf "%q"` to escape

Answer (score 1):

If `bash` (you have put as a tag) can be used, this is one solution :

```
printf "%s\0" "echo \"$2\" && ssh id@server echo \"${2@Q}\"" > sql1.txt
xargs -0 --arg-file=sql1.txt --max-procs=$1 --replace --verbose /bin/sh -c "{}"
```

${2@Q} is used to escape single quotes properly.

Also `xargs -0` prevents doubles quotes from being taken off.

Calling method :

```
bash script.bash 2 "tablename where last_load_dt = '2020-06-19'"
```

Comment: test2.bash: line 4: echo "$var2" && ssh id@server " echo "${2@Q}" " : bad substituion. Getting this error and the output after ssh  is still not showing single quotes. can you explain what does this -  "${2@Q}"  means.  Also i have series of operations few in current shell and remaining in remote shell. all of them concatenated by &&. Is there any simple way just to escape quote, Wanted to achieve it with minimal changes to my code

Comment: Take a look towards the end of this page : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion